# BASH - process status

Tags: bash

I'm trying to workout why this doesn't work

```
$result=`[ pgrep -x "gedit" ] && echo "Running" || echo "Stopped" `
```

I get:

`-bash: [: -x: binary operator expected`

If I run  `pgrep -x "gedit"` direct I get process ID's

Can someone advise why this fails ?
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you aware that `[ ]` is a synonym for the `test` command? And if so, why are you executing `pgrep -x "gedit"` inside a test block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the brackets to run and check the exit status of `pgrep`:

```
result=$(pgrep -x "gedit" > /dev/null && echo "Running" || echo "Stopped")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to solve your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

result=\`pgrep -x gedit && echo running || echo not\`

echo $result
```